# SQL select all in combined one-to-one table

Tags: sql

I have three SQL tables.

```
Table a
a.id
a.name
a.type

Table b
b.id
b.name
b.type

Table c
c.id
c.parent_id (contains the id from either a.id or b.id)
```

- Every record in table a has a one-to-one corresponding record in table c
- Every record in table b has a one-to-one corresponding record in table c

The problem:

```
I want to select all records from table C and get back:
c.id
the name of the parent (either a.name or b.name)
the type of the parent (either a.type or b.type)
```

Any suggestions for an effective way to do this?

Comment: I would suggest you to fix your design. It is a poorly design to have a table with an ID the can be of two different tables. That way you can not garantee referential integrity.

Comment: I agree with @JorgeCampos ; Instead of having `parent_id` in table `c` *(a pointer/reference/link **from** `c` **to** `a` and `b`)*, instead tables `a` and `b` should have a `c_id` field *(a pointer/reference/link **from** `a`/`b` **to** `c`)*.  Equally, if there is *always* a 1:1 relationship between `a` and `b`, then they should likely be a single table.  *(Unless you mean there is a 0..1 : 0..1 relationship.)*

Comment: I agree you should probably consider changing design, but if it's not a case you can take a look at RDBMS specific IF/ELSE statement. E.g. for MySQL: SELECT CASE WHEN a.name != null THEN a.name ELSE b.name

Comment: So perhaps then I should add all the fields of table c to each of the other tables.  I've resisted that so far because it feels I would then be duplicating the exact same code and I generally try to avoid code duplication.  Is this a better way to go? After that, do I then write a query that selects all from multiple tables (i.e. select all from table a and table b) ?

Comment: @Stan Nothing ever `!= NULL`, you need `IS NOT NULL`

Comment: @MatBailie, right :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT c.id, parent.name as parent_name, parent.[type] as parent_type
FROM tablec c
INNER JOIN tablea parent on parent.id = c.parent_id
UNION
SELECT c.id, parent.name as parent_name, parent.[type] as parent_type
FROM tablec c
INNER JOIN tableb parent on parent.id = c.parent_id
```

Using an inner join filters out rows where there is no match.

But I agree with Jorge's comment. It is a bad sign if parent_id is a reference to a column in a different table but cannot be made a legitimate foreign key because it references more than one column.

Answer (score 1):

```
select c.id,
a.name, a.type
from tablea a left join tableb b 
on a.id = b.id
left join tablec c
on a.id = c.parent_id or b.id = c.parent_id
union 
select c.id,
b.name, b.type
from tablea a left join tableb b 
on a.id = b.id
left join tablec c
on a.id = c.parent_id or b.id = c.parent_id
```

`union` is one way to do it as it only gives a unique value if for name and type columns from tables a and b.